Solutions to Orthogonal Matrix Equations
Given two unknown $n\times n$ rotations (special orthogonal matrices), $X, Y$, and given a series of $k$ known rotation matrix pairs $A_i, B_i$ such that:
$$Y=A_i X B_i \quad i\in1\ldots k$$
We wish to solve for both $X$ and $Y$. Clearly, we can represent this as a linear system with $2n^2$ unknowns. Then, if we have enough pairs, we can solve the system.
However, $X$ and $Y$ are actually composed of only $n(n-1)$ unknowns, so if we could find a "smart" way of solving this, we may get by with a smaller $k$ to solve for $X,Y$. So:

What is the minimal $k$ needed to uniquely determine $X,Y$?
For some $k$ larger than this value, is there a way of finding the least squares solution for $X,Y$ other than the classic solution for the $2n^2$ linear system?
Is the case $n=3$ special in any way?


The actual solutions can be complex though. I will first cover this case as this is also interesting:
Complex solution case. For the moment, I will seek for the best $X\in SU(n)$ and $Y\in SU(n)$ that satisfy $K=2$ constraints. Still, $A_i\in SO(n)$ and $B_i\in SO(n)$ for all $i$. I'll later incorporate the rest of the $K\geq 2$ constraints.  I will only consider non-degenerate configurations. For any pair of equations, we can write:
$$
Y=A_1 X B_1 = A_2 X B_2,
$$
Let me re-arrange this into:
$$
A_2^\top A_1 X = X B_2 B_1^\top, 
$$
and denote $B=B_2 B_1^\top$ and $A=A_2^\top A_1$ so that $AX=XB$. Note that $A\in SO(n)$ and $B\in SO(n)$. This gives a commutator where $A$ and $B$ share some structural similarity, having the same eigenspace. Rotation matrices are diagonalizable over the complex field and hence we write $B=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ to have:
$$
AXP = XP\Lambda,
$$
where $\Lambda$ contains the (potentially complex) eigenvalues of $B$ and $P$ denotes the complex eigenvectors. Let $X_P=XP$. Notice that the columns $x_i$ of $X_P$ can then be obtained as the solution to the optimization:
$$
A x_i = \lambda_i x_i,
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the individual eigenvalues. Note, $x_i$ lie in the null space of $(A-\lambda_i I)$. This is different than an eigenvalue problem, since $\lambda_i$ are given. After obtaining $X_P$, we can recover $X$ by: $X=X_P P^{-1}$. Plugging $X$ back to one of the original equations should give us $Y$.
Non-linear refinement. Now we can stop at this point or if we have more equations we can simply factor them in. We can do this by initializing from the explained solution and jointly minimizing all equations at our disposal, first for $Y$, to compute a better estimate and then for $X$, alternatingly. We can iterate these alternating updates until satisfied. In practice, a couple of iterations should already be sufficient. This should work for all dimensions including $3$. In practice, we can implement this as a projected gradient descent. Let me start by writing the energy:
$$
f(X,Y) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^K\|Y-A_i\cdot X\cdot B_i\|_2^{2},
$$
as well as the gradients of $f$ w.r.t. $(X,Y)$:
$$
\nabla_X f = 2kX - 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^K A_k^\top Y B_k^\top\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad
\nabla_Y f = 2kY - 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^K A_k X B_k.
$$
Setting $\nabla_X f=0$ and $\nabla_Y f=0$, respectively, we obtain:
$$
X_{t+1} = \frac1{k}\sum\limits_{k=1}^K A_k^\top Y_t B_k^\top\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad
Y_{t+1} = \frac1{k}\sum\limits_{k=1}^K A_k X_t B_k.
$$
We can alternatively iterate these updates to minimize $f$ and refine our guesses for $X$ and  $Y$, reducing the error gradually. Note that the convergence of each step is not guaranteed due to alternating-projections. But overall, this should work well for general cases.
If I were to write a MATLAB code for all of this:
%% Assume A1, B1, A2 and B2 are provided.
n = size(A1,1);

A = A2'*A1; 
B = B2'*B1;

[PA,LA]=eig(A);
la = diag(LA);
[PB,LB]=eig(B);
lb = diag(LB);

Xp = zeros(n);
for i=1:n
    Xp(:,i) = null(A-la(i).*eye(3));
end
X = Xp/PB;

% plug X back to get Y
Y = A1*X*B1;

% note that singular values and abs-det must be 1
disp(['abs(det(X)): ' num2str(abs(det(X)))]);
disp(['abs(det(Y)): ' num2str(abs(det(Y)))]);

%% moving into the iterative solution
k = 2; % for this example we have 2 As and 2 Bs.
Ak(:,:,1) = A1;
Ak(:,:,2) = A2;
Bk(:,:,1) = B1;
Bk(:,:,2) = B2;

% this is the total error we make
err = 0;
for i=1:k
    err = err + norm (Y-Ak(:,:,i)*X*Bk(:,:,i))^2;
end
curErr = sqrt(err);
disp(' ');
disp(['initial error: ' num2str(curErr)]);

% now iterate for all constraints
maxit = 5;
for it=1:5
    
    % first compute X
    Xi = zeros(size(X));
    for i=1:k
        Xi = Xi + (Ak(:,:,i)'*Y*Bk(:,:,i)')/k;
    end

    % projection of X onto SU(n)
    [U, ~, V] = svd(Xi);
    X = U*diag([ones(1,n-1),det(U*V')])*V';

    % then for Y
    Yi = zeros(size(Y));
    for i=1:k
        Yi = Yi + (Ak(:,:,i)*X*Bk(:,:,i))/k;
    end
    [U, ~, V] = svd(Yi);
    Y = U*diag([ones(1,n-1),det(U*V')])*V';

    % this is the total error we make
    err = 0;
    for i=1:k
        err = err + norm (Y-Ak(:,:,i)*X*Bk(:,:,i))^2;
    end
    curErr = sqrt(err);
    disp(['current error: ' num2str(curErr)]);
end

Real solution case. Since rotations are not real-diagonalizable, the above scheme does not apply to $SO(n)$. Instead we can start from an initial guess, say $X=I$ and then run the non-linear refinement. Of course, this is just to avoid the quadratic complexity you were mentioning.
Riemannian updates. If you do not like this projected gradient descent scheme for non-linear refinement, we can directly update rotations on the manifold of $SO(n)$ or $SU(n)$. Writing this down would blow up the response so I'm saving it for later and referring you to the great manopt package.

Thank you! One thing missing is that this gives a complex solution for $X$, while we need $X\in SO(n)$. It's also not clear how we guarantee a null space of one for each eigenvalue.

I agree. These are issues. For the former, I was looking into using $SU(2)$ embeddings of $SO(3)$ (through quaternions) and solving everything there before converting the result back. But seems like care must be taken and I did not have the time. Nevertheless, if you like to retrieve the closest matrix in $SO(3)$, you can take the real part of the result and project it onto $SO(3)$ using $U \mathrm{diag}(1,1,det(UV^\top)) V^\top$, where $X=USV^\top$ ($Y$ follows). For the latter, this frequently seems to happen and there might be an explanation. We need to investigate this further.

The answer is for the first question.
I think you meant $X,Y$ are orthonormal because you wrote they are composed of only $n(n-1)$ unknowns (degrees of freedom).
For every orthonormal matrix $V = (v_1,..,v_n)'$, we have:

$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ constraints $v_i^T\cdot v_j=0$ for $i\ne j$
$n$ constraints $v_i^T\cdot v_i = 1$ for $i =1,..,n$

In total, there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ constraints for the orthogonal matrix $V$ and so this matrix has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ unknowns (or degrees of freedom).
Return to the main problem, the two orthogonal matrix $X,Y$ has in total $n(n+1)$ constraints. For every $(A_i,B_i)$, we have $n^2$ equations. So, in the best case where no equation or constraint are overlapped, the minimum number $k$ can be determined by:
$$k\cdot n^2 +n(n+1)\ge 2n^2 \implies \color{red}{k \ge 1}$$
Then, it suffices 1 couple $(A_1,B_1)$ to determine $(X,Y)$.
In the worst case, perhaps you cannot determine $(X,Y)$. It is possible that for every $(A_i,B_i)$ with $n^2$ equations, these $n^2$ equations may be all equivalent to any $n^2$ of these $n(n+1)$ constraints.

Yes, $X,Y,A,B$ are orthonormal. Wikipedia defines an Orthogonal matrix as one with orthonormal columns, and that's the definition I used.

I'm also not convinced the $k=1$ solution exists. Take $n=3$, there are 6 unknowns, but since the pair $A,B$ isn't really independent, you could imagine that they only contribute $3$ equations per $k$.

@NathanielBubis Why is the pair $A,B$ not really independent?

Because they have to fullfil the constraint of $X,Y$.

@NathanielBubis In this case, I disagreed. The two $(A,B)$ contribute well $n^2$ equations for $X,Y$. The problem as I said is that these $n^2$ equations may be overlapped, either among them, either with the $n(n+1)$ constraints.

See the other answer which shows a unique solution for $k=2$. This leads me to believe that $k=1$ is not enough.

@NathanielBubis It depends on the configuration of $A$ and $B$. Even for the case $k = 1$ if all the $1 \cdot n^2 + n(+n) = 2n^2 + n > 2n^2$ are pairwise distinct (pairwise not equivalent), the number of equations is greater than the number of variables leads to no solution.
In the other answer, the author use numerical method by minimizing the function $f$. Of course, there is always solution (as $f$ is not necessary equal to $0$, it suffices to minimize $f$), even in the case $k \ge 3$. PS: I don't look in detail his solution, but I believe he brought to you the answer of you 2nd question.

Note that I provided both a closed form solution (for the case of $SU(3)$) and a numerical solution (supporting $SO(3)$).
